# Regex - Lookbehind with not fixed-length

Tags: java, regex, string, nlp, pattern-matching

I am trying to match a name in a sentence using Java RegEx. A name should be matched only if it is surrounded by normal text and not other names. For example, I would like to match the word **Obama** in the following sentence:

```
Americans said that Obama is ...
```

But not in the following one:

```
Americans said that Barack Obama is ...
```

To check that a token is a name I need to use something simple (an easy regex), without relying on more complex tools (i.e. NER). The regex uses a not-fixed width quantifier (*):

```
[A-Z][a-z]*
```

I can easily find a way to avoid matching names followed by other names with a negative look-ahead, by I can not use the same regex in a negative look-behind, because of the presence of the not-fixed width quantifier.

In other words, I can not use the following regex:

```
(?<![A-Z][a-z]*\s)Obama(?!\s[A-Z][a-z]*)
```

Do you have any other simple but effective ideas to solve this problem?

Comment: Why not just describe the "other case", like \s[a-z]+\s(Obama)\s[a-z]+\s ?

Comment: You are right, I was looking at the problem from the wrong perspective. I can use something like this: `(\s[a-z]+\s|\b\W\s|^)` before Obama.
Many thanks I think it can be a sub-optimal solution.

Comment: You'll get false negative with something like *Today Obama took the train*

Comment: @ThomasAyoub you are right, I've just added this exception. In this stage I can consider some false negatives.

Comment: Hi miccia, did you have time to check my answer below? If  it works for you please consider accepting, else, let know what needs clarifying.

Answer (score 3):

It is true that Java regex engine does not support *infinite* width lookbehind patterns, however, Java lookbehind pattern is *constrained width*, which means, we may use `{n,m}` limiting quantifiers inside it (with the min and max values set).

So, you can use

```
String str = "Americans said that Obama is ... Americans said that Barack Obama is ...";
Pattern ptrn = Pattern.compile("(?<!\\b[A-Z][a-z]{0,100}\\s)Obama(?!\\s+[A-Z][a-z]*)");
Matcher matcher = ptrn.matcher(str);
while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group(0));
}
```

See the [Java online demo](http://ideone.com/mxBnAV).

Since this assumes the word before can be 1 to 101 letters long, it is not the best approach, but may turn out sufficient.

Also, you may rely on capturing:

```
Pattern ptrn = Pattern.compile("(^|\\s[a-z]+\\s+)(Obama)(?!\\s+[A-Z][a-z]*)");
// ...
while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group(2));
}
```

See [another demo](http://ideone.com/fQQoWU), `Obama` will appear in Group 2, and Group 1 will match and consume `(^|\\s[a-z]+\\s+)` - start of string, or a whitespace + one or more lowercase ASCII letters and 1+ whitespaces.